# Crosstab report is not placing the columns as it should (Pentaho Report Designer)

Tags: java, pentaho, crosstab, pentaho-report-designer

I've created a Crosstab Report just to show a very simple table in the canvas. I added 1 row and a couple of columns and as you can see in the screenshot below the columns are stacked instead of in line:

[incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDo3r.png)

This is how it should look like:
[correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NwQW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, crosstab report in Pentaho Report Designer is a buggy pain, difficult to work with it, difficult to modify, and very limited.
From what I see in your screenshot, if you can modify your query to use a simple table instead of a crosstab, you'll save yourself a lot of pain.

Sorry, this is not a solution, but it's what I found working with PRD.

Comment: Thank you Ana. By now the ""solution"" I'd found is to create several crosstabs and with that at least I can move it as I want. Is not perfect but I guess it's what it is... 

However, as you seem to be experienced. Do you know if there's a guide anywhere to understand how the crosstab works? I mean, an official one?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't found any guide with crosstabs explain. To learn to work with PRD I used the book published by Packt Pub, it refers to an old edition of PRD, but nothing has changed in a lot of years (it's practically abandoned, Hitachi Vantara simply changes the release number without modifying anything) so you can use it now. I think there was a passing reference to crosstabs, but it was not enough, I tried to make a report, but I couldn't format it the way I liked, so I move on (we are not using PRD in production)